# C++ Sort Error "No instance of overloaded function.."

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

*I'm still very new to C++ and programming in general, so I apologize if haven't the right information the first time*

I started learning how to code with the book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition)" by Bjarne Stroustrup and I ran into some errors while using the code provided in chapter 4.6.4. Every time I go to run the code it tells me about "std::sort" and that there's no instance of overloaded function "std::sort" matches the argument list. There's also a new error in line 16 with i-1 as the IDE (Visual Studio 2013 Express) says the identifier is undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
std::vector<std::string>words;
for (std::string temp; std::cin >> temp;)
    words.push_back(temp);
std::cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << std::endl;

std::sort(words);

for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
    if (i == 0 || words[i–1] != words[i]) // is this a new word?
        std::cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

I can't seem to find out what's causing the error as I've put the required #include  but it still shows the error. Any explanation would help tremendously.

Comment: As the error says, there is no [overload of `std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) that takes a single argument. Is that really the example used in the book?

Comment: I rechecked and this is the exact example minus the inline comments that are a simple explanation. And I added the std:: because of habit forming purposes.

Comment: In that case I bet the book isn't actually calling `std::sort` but some other overload it defined that expects a container. Did you also omit a header include where that might be defined? And I copy-pasted your code into VS2013, the second problem you have is that the minus in `i–1` is actually an [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) or something similar. Replace that with a regular `-` and that error should go away.

Comment: After a bit of looking around the book, I neglected to see the "std_lib_facilities.h" that it mentions it uses, I honestly don't understand as to how I missed it. I would assume this is where the calling is defined. Sorry about that.

Comment: [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) does in fact contain `template<typename C> void sort(C& c)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::sort takes a pair of iterators.

```
std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
```

You could define your own helper function that takes one argument.

```
template<typename Container>
inline void sort(Container& c)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

You probably want to create your own namespace for the helper function.