# how does the std::sort() function in C++ work?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm using Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ as my guide and reference to learn programming and c++. In chapter 4.6.4 the book showed this snippet of code.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
        words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
    sort(words); // sort the words
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i]) // is this a new word?
            cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

in this example the sort function shows error, so I did a bit of searching up on google to get a better understanding of the sort function, and from what I understood the first perimeter of the sort function takes in the array or vector it is going to sort and the second variable tells the sort function where to sort it up to.

```
    int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
    sort(arr, arr[5]);
}
```

form what I understand the code snippet should sort up to the 6 element of the array, but the compiler shows me an error. So I tried different ways of trying to get it to work. However, only the way shown in geek for geek forum work.

```
 int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    /*Here we take two parameters, the beginning of the
    array and the length n upto which we want the array to
    be sorted*/
    sort(arr, arr + n);

    cout << "\nArray after sorting using "
        "default sort is : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

could someone explain how it really work

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491584/c-sort-error-no-instance-of-overloaded-function which explains (I think) that there's a special header _from the book, not the standard library_ that you need.  Go back and read that chapter again? (LInk to that special header is in the comments.)

Comment: Sorry for not inserting the full code but I was using std namespace in order to use this function

Comment: The brand new version of C++ , C++ 20, has a standard library called "ranges"  that can do this.  Stroustrop was probably anticipating this in his book (I guess, I don't have the book).  That version of sort isn't in `<algorithms>`.  Go look at that other question and _its comments_: it'll point you to the right direction here.

Comment: This doesn't' address the question, but that loop to display only unique values can be written more simply with `std::unique`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - it's an example from a _book_.  A _tutorial_ book.  A very _early_ example.

Comment: @davidbak -- what's your point?

Comment: @PeteBecker - that for the purposes of this question the OP isn't ready yet for std::unique?  I understand the urge to tell posters that their code could be better ... but in this case it seems off the point?  Don't get upset ...

Comment: @davidbak — I don’t treat other programmers like children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is working in C++20, if sort is from the ranges namespace. Is it mentioned in the book/tutorial your are reading?

`sort(arr, arr[5]);` in your terms, arr[5] is not "where", it's an array element, i.e. "what". "Where" is the address &arr[5] or &arr[n]. You could use std::begin(arr) and std::end(arr) instead of arr and &arr[n].

How std::sort work is very well explained with examples on [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: thanks alot you cleared up my misunderstanding